# Can Green color give Rest to Eyes?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

Is it correct that Green color gives rest to our eyes compare to other colors?

Comment: I think "eye-soothing" effect of green plants is more of a psychological/ neuro-psychological effect than directly a rest on eye.

Comment: Theoretically any light of visible spectrum (and their mixtures, including white light) will cause our rod and cone cells to work. none will make the rod and cone cells to "rest".

Comment: In a quick search I found some blog posts claiming that some scientists believe that green gives rest to the retina, because green is in the mid range of the visual spectrum and therefore "easiest" to detect.. Of course these posts didn't cite any sources for that. So, I couldn't track down the supposed research..

Comment: @Rk003 not sure, if you're talking to me, but as I said: I couldn't find a reliable source for that claim and therefore don't believe it.

Comment: Similar question and answer is  [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/does-green-cause-less-eye-strain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our eyes, the dioptric difference between the dispersion of red versus blue light is approximately 2D. 
[image: Sensitivity of eyes to coloured spectrum]
Remembering that the human eye's peak spectral sensitivity lies at 550 nm (green), the human retina is deliberately placed such that it is in between the dispersion of white light, i.e., between red and blue. This optimizes the best level of focus specifically for its peak spectral sensitivity. The pupil and the nucleus of the lens also help to minimize chromatic aberration.

In short, the eye is constructed such that it is easiest to focus on green light, which is in the middle of the visible spectrum and has the strongest receptors.